# Accessing Symfony parameters from Service

Tags: php, symfony, service, parameters

I have written a service which uses guzzle to make a request to another site. The guzzle parameters (URL, headers etc.) must be configurable, so I have stored them in `app/config/parameters.yml`

But as the service does not have access to the container, how can I retrieve the parameters?

Comment: inject parameters into service

Comment: Is there no other way? What if I need a bunch of other parameters, I don't want to have too many arguments in my service constructor.

Comment: It's better to have many arguments than accesso to the container.. if you have too many arguments means that your service do more than one thing so you could split into many service that become collaborators of your original service @dev0

Comment: The other approach is use an extension and build your service definition programaticaly.  It is what most 3rd party bundles do.  Bit of a learning curve.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config.html In most cases, it is easier to just inject what you need.

Comment: What about using the DotEnv component? https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you don't want to pass many parameters to constructor,

a) you can pass many parameters as array.

```
parameters:
    my_params:
         foo: bar
         baz: 1

services:
    app.my_service:
    class: \yourservice\
    arguments:
        - '%my_params%'
```

b) you can use setters

```
services:
    app.my_service:
        class: \yourservice\
        calls:
            - [setParameterA, ['%first_param%']]
            - [setParameterB, ['%second_param%']]
            - ...
```

2. For your case is better to create Guzzle Client from Factory with given params. You can define many various clients and inject the specific one into your service.

`

```
services:
    app.client_factory:
        class: AppBundle\Service\ClientFactory

    app.some_client:
        class: GuzzleHttp\Client
        factory: 'app.client_factory:create'
        arguments:
            - []
            -
              base_uri: '%url%/%version%'
              headers:
                  User-Agent: 'MyAgent 0.1'
                  Accept: 'application/json'
                  content-type: 'application/json'
            - ~

    app.my_service:
        class: \yourservice\
        arguments:
            - '@app.some_client'
```